# How to close all of the activities of running app and Re-launch a fresh app on click

Tags: android, single-instance

I'm having the app with multiple screen
My App Launch from splash(Launcher)->Home Screen->Child Screen.
When User Tap on URL app directly jumps to Child Screen(Application need).
But when user tap on URL a new instance of application launched which I don't want. I want to close the the existing app and launch the fresh app with Child Screen. Each activity is having   `android:launchMode="singleTop"`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To launch the fresh Application I found this solution and its working fine for me

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Firstctivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent );
finish();
```

It will close ongoing `Task` and create new one for me.. :)